# Personal passive

Tags: passive-voice

I read [an article at grammarbank](http://www.grammarbank.com/it-is-said-that.html) , and understood that when we want to make personal passive for all of tenses we use "**is** thought (seen,said,...)" or "**are**  thought (Seen,said,.. )",

but after that,  over on [baladre.info](http://baladre.info/english/sedaviwebfront/passivepersonal.htm), I saw question number 6,

> "Someone saw him pick up the gun"

and the answer is "He **was seen** to pick up the arm" .

So I am confused. Is the answer to the question correct? Shouldn't it be changed to "He is seen to have pick up the gun"?

Comment: From the first link they provide this example of a sentence in the simple past passive voice * It’s said that he **was** rich in the past.*

Comment: What is a "personal" passive? Both past and present tense passive sentences are grammatical.

Answer (score 1):

The article at Grammar Bank that you linked to is showing a pattern of making a special kind of sentence that uses the passive voice.  But the passive voice can be used in many other ways, such as "He was seen to pick up the gun" (or, equivalently, "He was seen picking up the gun").

A sentence following the pattern shown in that article would be

> He was believed to have picked up the gun.

The verb *to see* is rather different from the verbs being worked with in that particular article.

Answer (score 0):

Completely different usage.  "is thought" and "is said" *to be* something are about ongoing states, as in being rich, or being strange or being absent etc.  Same as "is seen as" or "was thought of as".

"Was seen *to* (verb)" describes someone observing an incident, in this case, the picking up of a gun. With its pronounced use of the passive (which shifts emphasis away from the implied subject), it has the flavor of a witness report, as in a policeman reading from his notebook in court. It sounds more ponderous than "I saw".